# Ellipsoidal Covariance Matrix

Tags: covariance, discriminant, artificial-intelligence

What does it mean when you say  "Covariance matrix are highly ellipsoidal"? I am reading  **Regularized Discriminant Analysis" by Jerome H. Friedman 1989** and it uses this term very often "Covariance matrices are all equal and Highly ellipsoidal "?

Comment: It's quite useless just to say you're reading "a paper". Perhaps you're more likely to get an answer if you tell us *which* paper it is.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. The paper is titled "Regularized Discriminant Analysis" by Jerome H. Friedman 1989, published in Journal of the American Statistical Association

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The covariance matrix of a set of variables is always symmetric by definition, which means that it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix.

That being said, we can visualize the matrix as an ellipsoid whose axes have sizes given by it eigenvalues, and that has been rotated by the corresponding orthogonal matrix.

In this context the term *ellipsoidal* is being used in opposition to *spherical*. Being highly ellipsoidal means that the eigenvalues have very different magnitudes.